# What is the need of Void class in Java

Tags: java, void

I am not clear with the class `java.lang.Void` in Java. Can anybody elaborate in this with an example.

Answer (score 62):

It also contains `Void.TYPE`, useful for testing return type with reflection:

```
public void foo() {}
...
if (getClass().getMethod("foo").getReturnType() == Void.TYPE) ...
```

Comment: +1 for pointing that it is used in reflection to specify the type of a method, which has no return value.

Comment: Actually there is also void.class (lowercase!) which would also works perfectly in your example. So Void is not needed there.

Comment: In fact, Void.TYPE is defined as  
public static final Class<Void> TYPE = Class.getPrimitiveClass("void");
Which itself is void.class.

Comment: @Willi: Yes, I forget about `void.class`. Sorry.

Comment: Did `void.class` exist in Java 1.1?

Comment: @Cephalopod yes, check out javadoc param @since for Void class it says: `@since   JDK1.1`

Answer (score 52):

Say you want to have a generic that returns void for something:

```
abstract class Foo<T>
{
    abstract T bar();
}

class Bar
    extends Foo<Void>
{
    Void bar()
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that Void class exists since jdk 1.1.

Comment: I like TofuBeer's answer, but Roman raised an interesting point there.

Comment: It isn't there strictly for that, it was just the first use that jumped to mind.  The reflection answer is why it was introduced.

Comment: Had this use case and was stumped when javac wrote `This method must return a result of type Void`. Just returning `(null)` didn't come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a pragmatic case where void.class is really useful.
Suppose you need to create an annotation for class fields, and you need to define the class of the field to get some information about it (in example, if the field is an enum, to get list of potential values). In that case, you would need something like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PropertyResourceMapper
{
    public Class acceptedValues() default void.class;
}
```

to be used like this:

```
@PropertyResourceMapper(acceptedValues = ImageFormat.class, description = "The format of     the image (en example, jpg).")
private ImageFormat format;
```

I have used this to create a custom serializer of classes to a proprietary format.

Answer (score -2):

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html):

```
public final class Void
extends Object
```

The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

```
static Class<Void> TYPE
```

The Class object representing the primitive Java type void.

```
TYPE
public static final Class<Void> TYPE
```

The Class object representing the primitive Java type void.

Comment: This is just a copy+paste of the documentation, not a real answer.

Comment: @Hugo That is true, but I still found this to be the most useful answer. Other answers sidestep why it exists. It is the Class representation of a primitive type. Like Integer or Double.

Comment: You should also mention that the only term that inhabits Void is null.