# Cannot resolve symbol 'Void'

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

At the head of my class (I am taking over a project from someone else), I have the following:

```
using Java.Util;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;
using Void = Java.Lang.Void;
```

Void, is showing in red, with a "**Cannot resolve symbol 'Void'**" and cannot see what I may be missing.

I have checked the PC where this came from (and the application does build on that one) and have installed the same (yes, I saw, newer, but specifically installed the "same" items) Java items:

- Java 7 Update 45
- Java 6 Update 31
- Java SE Development Kit 6 Update 31

This hasn't made any change.

I have checked the 'References' branch of the project and everything is showing the same (in fact, I cannot see a specific reference to Java anywhere)

Any help would be appreciated to sort this.

Please understand that I am not looking to change the code; just to get the code (as is) to compile without error.

[Update]

When I type out **Java.Lang.** the intellisense does not show **Void** in the dropdown list

[Further Update]

This project is tied to the development for a tablet; for which I hadn't installed some of the development software - installing these has resolved the issue and I can only assume that the Java namespace is buried within the software. Whilst there's no specific answer in the responses, most of the comments have certainly helped to steer me in the right direction.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Because it *is* C#.

Comment: 'using' is a C# keyword

Comment: this is the very first time I see this, +1

Comment: `Void` is not a thing in Java; `void` is a thing. BTW, I don't see how you can get it to compile when it is incorrect.

Comment: Void is not a thing in Java? Really?

Comment: Which "Void" is red? Left or right?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - it's the right one (in Java.Lang.Void)

Comment: try to use      using V = Java.Lang.Void;java.lang.Void

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - indeed, because it is in a C# project

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj - The code compiles without this error on the PC from where it came, so there should be no need to change the "code"; the issue must be with something that is not installed on my PC, referenced or configured incorrectly, which is what I need to resolve.

Comment: Did you try the `Clean --> ReBuild` for your project

Comment: Is java added in your build path??

Comment: @V4Vendetta - Yes, with no effect. Also, as far as I know, there would be no need to use "Clean", if you use "ReBuild" (a ReBuild includes the Clean)

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj - could you advise where I would check that Java is added to the build path?

Comment: @SeanAnderson Better remove the Java tag because this is specific to the C# development environment, and with the Java tag you are just attracting attention (and misguided advice!) of Java specialists. You should also name the technology by which you "import" Java into a C# project.

Comment: You can't use Java classes from a C# project, at least not directly... are you using something like [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I suspect it is IKVM.NET

Comment: If its the right hand one.. then you have a reference problem. It cannot find the type in the namespace you've provided. It still looks awfully weird..

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352447/what-is-the-need-of-void-class-in-java posts

Comment: You should probably specify __in the question__ that this is C#, not Java. The context seems very important here.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible ways a C# project consuming Java bits,

- Microsoft J#, which has been dead for a long time.
- [IKVM.NET](http://www.IKVM.net), which originates from Mono.
- [dot42, a C# to Android compiler](http://www.dot42.com), which compiles C# to Android.
- [Xamarin.Android (aka Mono.Android)](http://xamarin.com).

Based on the fragment you pasted I think you might be opening a Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio, as the using clauses match,

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=N%3aJava.Util

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aJava.Lang.Void

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aJava.Lang.Object

Thus, you need to have Xamarin.Android completely installed on this machine. What you have (JRE and JDK) is obviously not enough.

dot42 does not have `Java.Lang.Void` and `Java.Lang.Object`, http://docs.dot42.com/Reference/NS.Java.Lang

Answer (score 0):

I think these links would be helpful for you.

[What is the difference between java.lang.Void and void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839042/what-is-the-difference-between-java-lang-void-and-void)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/Void.html

Comment: This would imply a change to code; as commented this was not about correcting code, it was about getting an application to compile (which it was doing on another PC)

Answer (score 0):

FAIL:

```
using Java.Lang.Void;
import Java.Lang.Void;
```

SUCCESS:

```
import java.lang.Void;
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to use import instead of using.

```
import Java.Util.*;
Object blah = new Java.Lang.Object;
```

If you want to create an object that is `null`, do this:

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

If you want to add data set it equal to data such as a number.

```
obj = 7;
```

Comment: As discussed in the comments, this isn't Java.

Comment: But no one answered it as a response.

Comment: Yes, because neither your answer nor "it's not Java" is a solution for this question. It's about getting that C# code to compile, with those using directives as they are.

Comment: Seemed to me like he was trying to program in java. Everything in his post relates to java. If you think he was trying to program in C# then you are wrong.

Comment: I can confirm (as per the [Further Updates] in my original post; that this was resolved by installing some missing components. For clarification on the commnets: +grexter89 was correct that it was about getting C# code to compile (without making code changes) and +CrazyJohnny it is not code written in Java.

Comment: Sounds like you solved your problem!? You should post it as an answer to this question, so that other people with a similar problem can quickly get help here.