# Why does public void Void() {...} compile in Java?

Tags: java, void

I have this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Void();
    }

    private static void Void() {
        System.out.print("Hello");
    }
}
```

Since `java.lang.Void` is a class in Java, why can that be the method name?

Comment: works with `private static void Integer()` as well.

Comment: Or even `Test()` - this is a common mistake. Newbies often add a return type when trying to create a constructor thereby creating a strangely named method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the need of Void class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352447/what-is-the-need-of-void-class-in-java)

Comment: @naimdjon Replace the `java.lang.Void` with `java.lang.Integer`. Does that linked question still answer this one?

Comment: You can even create your own class or method  named `String`, or `Object`. It's not smart because you're going to make a very confusing program, but these are just names, not any more special than other names in a Java program.

Comment: There are **numerous** classes in java. Forbidding any method to have the same name as any class would be untenable

Comment: @naimdjon `Void` is just an example, this isn't about what `Void` is for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Void` is not [reserved keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) (`void` is but Java is case-sensitive so `void` is not equal `Void`). Similarly `String`, `Integer`, `Boolean` and so on are also not reserved.

You can use `Void` to name whatever you want: classes, methods, fields. But being able to do something doesn't automatically mean that you should. It is not wise creating confusion by naming methods (or something else) with names already used to represents something else.

Comment: Note that you're free to do this but then s̶u̶f̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶b̶a̶d̶ ̶d̶e̶s̶i̶g̶n̶ ̶c̶h̶o̶i̶c̶e̶s̶  deal with the side effects of this design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a fully object-oriented language. That means that everything, even primitive types (like int or double) has a class object in the JDK. Some examples include `Integer` vs. `int`, `Boolean` vs. `bool` and so forth. And, since every object in Java inherits from the class `Object`, these enable you to use boxing and unboxing (explicitly casting a class instance as an Object instance) with every type, including primitive types.

`Void` is simply a placeholder for the `void` keyword in Java. It is an uninstantiable object which has no methods or properties. And since `Void`'s full name is `java.lang.Void`, you can create a class object or even a method with the same name in your own namespace, as long as you haven't explicitly imported `java.lang.Void` into your class file.

Comment: Re your first paragraph. It's worth noting that there's no primative `void`

Comment: I never stated that void is a primitive type

Comment: In that case what is your first paragraph trying to say?

Comment: I'm merely explaining that everything in Java is an object, including primitive types. Otherwise, it would be difficult to understand why there's a Void class.

Comment: I wouldn't say thats strictly speaking true. You could remove the Double, Float etc classes from java and retain the primatives. The primatives are explicitly not objects. The boxed versions are just provided for convenience for use with ArrayLists etc. I know in more recent versions autoboxing and autounboxing has made them more are more closely related to their primative cousins but in early versions of java they lived largely seperate lives (much like a `Vector2d` contains 2 doubles a `Double` contains 1 `double`)

Comment: Btw `java.lang.*` is automatically imported, and it doesn't matter if class `Foo` is imported you can still have a method called `Foo` as well. For example the following is fine; `public String String(){return "hello";}`