# What does `void.class` denote?

Tags: java, class, primitive-types

In my code I (accidentially) wrote `void.class` (**not `Void.class`**) which was happily accepted by the compiler. Until now I thought that the primites are no real objects (not only `void`, also talking about `int`, etc... here), so they'd have no class.

I'm talking about all the "primitive classes". Every primitive type has a class denoted by `<primitivetype>.class`, for example `float.class`

- What "`Class`" is referred to by such a "primitive class", e.g. `void.class`?
- what are the possible use cases of these "primitive classes"?

  - Especially, do they offer a constructor?
  - Can we make meaningful instance checks like `int.class.isInstance(2.3f)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the need of Void class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352447/what-is-the-need-of-void-class-in-java)

Comment: The javadoc of isInstance says: *If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false.*

Comment: @DavidTitarenco That question does not address `void.class`, or the other primitive classes e.g. `int.class` (the top answer - including comments -  kind-of does)

Comment: @WorldSEnder: gotcha, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void.class` is the object used in reflection to indicate that a method has `void` return type. If you write `method.getReturnType();`, this object may be returned.

`int.class` can represent both arguments and return types.

You can write `int.class.isInstance(...)` but it will always return `false`, because the argument is an `Object`.

No `Class` object has an accessible constructor.

Both `int.class.getConstructors()` and `int.class.getDeclaredConstructors()` return an empty array. There are no constructors for primitive types.

Comment: "No Class object has an accessible constructor"  I'm sure the OP means `Class.getConstructors()`, not a `Class` constructor itself.

Comment: @TavianBarnes You're right - it could well mean that. I've added a final sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The first obvious problem of `Class` is that it also represents interfaces :)

Prior to java5, `Class` is used to represent all java types, including primitive types. This is out of convenience, and it worked fine.

After generics was introduced, java types get a lot richer. `java.lang.reflect.Type` was introduced to include all types. Unfortunately, it incorporates the old messy `Class`, making an even bigger mess. The hierarchy of `Type` just doesn't make sense.

Now, `void` is not even a type!  So `Class` also include a non-type. That is out of convenience, as other answers have shown. Similarly, [a wildcard is not a type either](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html#Wild_Type), yet `WildcardType extends Type`!

---

Could `void` have been designed as a type in the beginning? Why not. It's a primitive type of `0` bits, having exactly one value (aka, a unit type). I'm not sure how to feel if people write

```
void foo(void param){
    param = bar();  // void bar(){...}
```

but at least I'll be happy if I could write

```
void foo(...){
    return bar();
```

see also John Rose's [comment](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-September/011020.html)

Comment: a cleaner representation of java type if anyone's interested - http://zhong-j-yu.github.io/od/1.0.0/javadoc/bayou/jtype/JavaType.html

Answer (score 0):

Void is a placeholder for return type void used in Reflections.

Example:-  `void.class` is the return type for the methods returning void as in `main` method below:-

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{

    Method mh = A.class.getMethod("main",String[].class);
    System.out.println(mh.getReturnType() == void.class);

    }
}
```