# How can I get a Class object form primitive?

Tags: java, reflection

Obviously this is possible (as `Class` has `isPrimitive()` method) but how I can do this directly?
E.g. reflection api able to cast a primitive type to Class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class TestClass {
       
        public static void m(){}
        public static void m(Object o){}
        public static void m(int i){}
        public static void m(Integer i){}
       
        public static void main(String[] args){
               
                TestClass tc=new TestClass();
                Method[] mtds=tc.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
               
                for (int i = 0; i < mtds.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print(mtds[i].getName());
                        Class[] prms=mtds[i].getParameterTypes();
                        for (int j = 0; j < prms.length; j++) {
                                System.out.print("-"+prms[j].getCanonicalName());
                                       
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                }        
        }
}
```

output is:

> m
>
> m-java.lang.Object
>
> m-int
>
> m-java.lang.Integer
>
> main-java.lang.String[]

Integer and int are different so it is not autoboxing. Anything (except creating an utility class with reflection and getParameterTypes() ) do not come at my mind (everything else I've tried failed).

Comment: I don't understand your question. There are class literals for primitives. But given a primitive value (or rather a variable of a primitive type), you already know its type. You wouldn't need to use something similar to `getClass`.

Comment: What has this to do with autoboxing? Can you tell what is your expected output? Not really clear.

Comment: @RohitJain - my first thought was that `int` is wrapped to `Integer` so it will be possible to get the Class object from int.But obviously I was wrong :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `int` you normally do `int.class` or `Integer.TYPE`. Similarly for the other primitive types (e.g. `double.class`).

Comment: aah.Great! Didn't know this.Will accept this after 10 minmutes.

Comment: Even `void` has `void.class` and `Void.TYPE`

Comment: @PeterLawrey - this is pretty interesting.Is there are cases where this can be useful?

Comment: How does and when `int.class` or `Integer.TYPE` be useful ?? If you could throw some light.

Comment: @hagrawal - for me it was useful with reflection as in the example- when I'm searching for a method with exact types of parameters. Though it is interesting how `void` could be useful for something (anyway it is good to know it).

Comment: @npocmaka http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352447/what-is-the-need-of-void-class-in-java

Comment: You can need `Main.class.getMethod("main", String[].class).getReturnType() == void.class` and also `Callable<Void>` if you have a callable which doesn't actually return anything. (It might throw a checked exception however so you can't use `Runnable` either)